# Empty area of anonymous feedback window

Tags: bug, design, post-feedback, anonymous-visitors

If you have not being logged to SE network and make a vote for some post you will see the following popup:

> [image: sign up or log in]

But if you already logged to some other site this popup looks differently:

> [image: join]

Empty area below the "Join this community" link looks weird. I think the final dimensions of this popup should be reduced if it's possible.

Comment: Made 2 of my votes to close this as duplicate :)